# Unramified extensions of local fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field, unramified-extension

Let $(K,\nu)$ be a local field. Let $L,K’$ be two unramified extensions of $K$ such that
$$[L:K]=[K’:K]=n$$
then $L \cong K’$.
Searching on web I found a prof on “algebraic number theory” of Milne (page 127-128), but it hasn’t more details.
Let $k$ be the residue field of $K$ and let $k’$ be the residue field of $L$ and $K’$. $K’L$ is unramified over $K$ since $K’$ and $L$ are unramified over $K$ (I found this prof on neukirch book page 153-154) with residue field $k’$, so
$$[LK’:K]=[k’:k]=[K’:K] $$
and this prove that $L\cong K’$.
I do not understand because the residue field of $LK’$ is $k’$, can anyone explane this?

Comment: The resique field of $K$ is $k\cong \cong \Bbb{F}_q$ then both $L$ and $K'$ are the splitting field of $x^{q^n}-x$, by Hensel lemma and $[k':k]\le [K':K]$. I don't think there is any more clever way.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but how this prove that $k’$ is the residue field of $LK’$ ?

Comment: It proves that $L=K'=LK'$ whenever both are subfield of a common field. If they are not then $LK'$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you, in this way is very easy.

Comment: Today I’m trying to complete this proof on my notebook, but i have a doubt. I take $f(x)=x^{q^n}-x$, this is a separable polynomial in $k$ with zeros in $k’$. So, by Hensel lemma, $split_K f \subseteq K’$ and $split_K f \subseteq L$, but I’m not able to conclude. In that way i use $[k’:k]=[K’:K]$ ?

Comment: It depends on what you assume. With Hensel lemma you are proving that the splitting field of $x^{q^n}-x$ is the smallest extension with residue field $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ and that it satisfies $[k':k]=[K':K]$ and that any extension with residue field $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ contains $K'$. Then you are allowed to say that $K'/K$ is unramified of degree $n$ iff $K'=K(\zeta_{q^n-1})$.